# Javascript examples from Duckett's book not working

Tags: javascript, object-construction

I am learning javascript from Duckett's book and have noticed that the examples from the book were not working when I copied them onto my text edit.
The code is on the website so, I downloaded the files and tried opening them but the same issues showed up on both Chrome and Safari. Here is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript &amp; jQuery - Chapter 3: Functions, Methods &amp; Objects - 
          Object Constructor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/c03.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TravelWorthy</h1>
    <div id="info">
        <h2>hotel availability</h2>
    <div id="hotelName"></div>
    <div id="availability">
        <p id="rooms"></p>
        <p>rooms left</p>
    </div>
    <script src="js/multiple-objects.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

// Set up the object
var hotel = new Object();
hotel.name = 'Park';
hotel.rooms = 120;
hotel.booked = 77;
hotel.checkAvailability = function() {
  return this.rooms - this.booked;  
};

var elName = document.getElementById('hotelName'); // Get element
elName.textContent = hotel.name;                   // Update HTML with property of the 
object

var elRooms = document.getElementById('rooms');    // Get element
elRooms.textContent = hotel.checkAvailability();   // Update HTML with result of method
```

I've turned off smart quotes and Javascript is enabled. This example is supposed to return the availability of the rooms, but where the numbers should show up, it's blank. This is the third example similar to this that doesn't work.

Comment: JavaScript code has to be inside a `<script>` block.

Comment: The JavaScript is contained in an external file that’s why I used <script src= “”>

Comment: When I copy pasted the js above directly into the html file and inside is script block, it did what it’s supposed to do, so I know the js is good, I guess I’m having trouble when trying to add it as an external js file